# An early separation of variables problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The problem: find $y$ as a function of $x$ if $\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{y}{x}=0$.

The constraint: this problem comes in a first chapter on integration, where only u-substitution and separation of variables have really been covered, and where, for example, $\int \frac{dx}{x}$ has (explicitly) not been discussed. Separation of variables gives $\frac{dy}{y}=-\frac{dx}{x}$, but the reader is not equipped for that integration.

A reader could imagine the shape of the differential equation and make a guess that $y=\frac{c}{x}$, or maybe by rearrangement of the terms as $\frac{y\ dx+x\ dy}{x\ dx}=0$ recognize something like the product rule and make the jump to $xy=c$ as the original function. I don't think those intuitive routes are what the author intended.

The question: How can this problem be solved, short of being able to integrate $\frac{dx}{x}$?

Comment: What is the textbook?

Comment: George Simmons Calculus, it’s one of the review questions at the end of Chapter 5.

Comment: Because the equation is suggesting that somehow taking the derivative puts the function on the same footing as losing a power by $1$, guess the solution is of the form $y=Cx^r$ and solve for $r$

Comment: This is problem 36. In order to solve problem 35, one has to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for the curves of the family $xy=c$. I'm not a mind reader, but I suspect the author did this on purpose...

Comment: @Gonçalo good eye, yes that problem did prime me for the current exercise. I knew $xy=c$ satisfies the equation. If you know that, you can reformulate the differential equation as, e.g. $\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{c}{x^2}=0$ and solve even if you can't yet integrate $\frac{dx}{x}$. But then I got curious, what is the author driving at? That this exercise is impossible without either good guesses or $\int \frac{dx}{x}$ available? So I tried to solve it without prior knowledge, with only the tools developed so far in the book. I wrote the post wondering if I missed an obvious route to solve.

Answer (score 0):

As a hint: look at these $$\int \frac {dx}{x}=\int\frac 1x dx=\ln|x|+c\\\int \frac {dy}{yx}=\int\frac 1y dy=\ln|y|+c\\
\int \frac {df(x)}{f(x)}=\int\frac 1{f(x)}x dx=\ln|f(x)|+c$$in your question $\frac{dy}{y}+\frac{dx}{x}=0\ \to \int \frac{dy}{y} +\int \frac{dx}{x}=0 \to \ln y+\ln x +c_!+c_2=0$

Comment: Totally right - but I’m not asking for that solution. I’m asking if it can be solved if you *don’t* know that integral yet.